# Are comments considered tokens?

Tags: comments

Usually we consider Identifiers, keywords, separators, operators and literals to be tokens. Can we also consider a comment to be a token?

Comment: As this [Java doc](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/15-200/lectures/tokens/lecture.html) said comments are considered as tokens as Identifiers, keywords, separators, operators and literals

Comment: _Can we also consider a comment to be a token?_ 'We' being who? 'We compilers' or 'We parsers' or what??

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the language, the compiler and how it implements lexing. In C and C++, comments are stripped by the preprocessor and never make it to the real parser. In languages that don't have a preprocessor, then comments have to be treated as meaningless structures that have to be instantly discarded.

A constant in these examples is that the program doesn't want to do anything useful with comments. This is not a universal truth. If you make a tool to manipulate source code instead of trying to compile it to machine code, then it could make sense to implement comments as some sort of tokenizable structure since you could want to manipulate them.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, comments are not considered as tokens. The compiler doesn't take them into account at all. At least for C# and C++ you will not find them in the assembly or executable that the corresponding compilers produce respectively. Regarding the Java, I could assume that something similar happens but you have to search it, in order to verify it. They just help the readers of a program to catch up with more quickly than delve into details at the first read of the code.

Comment: But then, how does the intelisense mark the comments with a special color?